# PHP: вернуть результат каждой функции запущенной через pcntl_fork()

Tags: многопоточность, php

Изучаю fork в php и вот проблема не могу вернуть из функции которую форкаю в массив к примеру, чтоб потом работать с этими данными

```
<?php
function shell_ls($row)
{
    echo $row . "\n" . shell_exec('ls /tmp');
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if (!$pid) {
        shell_ls($i);
        exit($i);
    }
}
while (pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1) {
    $status = pcntl_wexitstatus($status);
    echo "Child $status completed\n";
}
```

Этот код работает и пишет сразу в консоль, как заставить функцию shell_ls возвращать значения

```
function shell_ls($row)
{
    return $row . "\n" . shell_exec('ls /tmp');
}
```

а под $pid замутить добавление в массив

```
if (!$pid) {
    $result[]=shell_ls($i);
    exit($i);
}
```

ну и соответственно вывести результат в конце выполнения fork()

```
print_r($result);
```

Comment: pcntl\_fork - это создание нового процесса (насколько понимаю, не треда, а именно процесса), поэтому придется задействовать тот или иной вид IPC - что бы не делалось в форке, это уже осуществляется вне текущего процесса, он не имеет доступа. Проще всего перед форком создавать уникальный ключ, по которому в базу данных скидывать результаты, и после отработки всех форков эти данные из БД подтягивать, если есть возможность - использовать [пайпы](http://runnable.com/UnAPQnvhzbFlAAAn/how-to-communicate-between-php-processes-posix-named-pipes-) или вообще proc\_open.

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с многопроцессорностью при изучении сокетов в php, там есть примерно такой текст:

```
list($pid, $master, $workers) = $this->spawnWorkers(); //создаём дочерние процессы

    if ($pid) {//мастер
            fclose($server);//  мастер не будет обрабатывать входящие соединения на основном сокете
            //$masterclass=
            $WebsocketMaster = new WebsocketMasterHandler($workers);//мастер будет пересылать сообщения между воркерами
            $WebsocketMaster->start();
    } else {//воркер
            //$this->log("start worker with $server, $master");
            $WebsocketHandler = new WebsocketWorkerHandler($server, $master);
            $WebsocketHandler->start();
    }

        function spawnWorkers(){

        $master = null;
        $workers=[];
        $i=0;
        while ($i < $this->config['workers']) {
                $i++;
                //создаём парные сокеты, через них будут связываться мастер и воркер
                $pair = stream_socket_pair(STREAM_PF_UNIX, STREAM_SOCK_STREAM, STREAM_IPPROTO_IP);
                $pid = pcntl_fork();//создаём форк
                if ($pid == -1) {
                        die("error: pcntl_fork\r\n");
                } elseif ($pid) { //мастер
                        //$this->log('i will be master');
                        fclose($pair[0]);
                        $workers[$pid] = $pair[1];//один из пары будет в мастере
                } else { //воркер
                        //$this->log('i will be slave');
                        fclose($pair[1]);
                        $master = $pair[0];//второй в воркере
                        break;
                }
            }
            if(!$this->config['workers']){
                $pair = stream_socket_pair(STREAM_PF_UNIX, STREAM_SOCK_STREAM, STREAM_IPPROTO_IP);
                list($pid, $master, $workers) = [0,$pair[0],[$pair[1]]];
                }
            return array($pid, $master, $workers);
        }
```

Родитель создаёт ($this->config['workers']) воркеров и общается с ними данными, запакованными json через созданные сокеты, переданные в контроллеры мастера и воркеров через $workers и $master соответственно, а $server создаётся до приведённого кода через stream_socket_server - это коннект, который слушают все воркеры и принимают через него клиентские соединения... сама статья [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/company/ifree/blog/209864/)